# passing data from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have an activity which have a method in it. In this method I write

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.putExtra("geoLat", geoLat); // latitude
intent.putExtra("geoLng", geoLng); // longitude
```

There is another activity which have the following line of code

```
Intent intent1=getIntent();
double geoLat = intent1.getDoubleExtra("geoLat", 0.0);
double geoLng = intent1.getDoubleExtra("geoLng", 0.0);
```

Problem geoLat and geoLng are always 0.0

Please correct it where it is going wrong.
Or any other way to get this.

Thanks!!

Comment: did you checked geoLat, geoLng before passing , that its not 0.0 ??

Comment: 11-12 00:10:58.247: VERBOSE/Acticity(642): hiiiiii **3.7422005E7**
11-12 00:10:58.267: VERBOSE/Acticity(642): hiiiiii **-1.22084095E8**

Comment: post complete code of both the classes .

Comment: you have to do setResult(int, Intent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Intent intent1=getIntent();
double geoLat =this.getIntent().getDoubleExtra(geoLat);
double geoLng= this.getIntent().getDoubleExtra(geoLng);
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
intent.putLong("something", 10.0);

/* --------------------------------*/

getIntent().getExtras().getLong("something");
```

Comment: Null Pointor Exception on this line.

Comment: You're doing something funny.

Comment: hehehe what is funny in this picture?

Answer (score 0):

Now I might be wrong about this, but don't you handle the part in the second activity with `Bundles`?

Try this in your second activity:

```
Bundle bun = getIntent().getExtras();
double geoLat = bun.getDoubleExtra("geoLat");
double geoLng = bun.getDoubleExtra("geoLng");
```

At least, that's how I always do it and I never had any problems with `Doubles` or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you give it a try with the debugger and break points? It would be interesting to see whether the problem is with the "writing" or with the "reading"